# Find if a string exists in a folder with text files

Tags: python

I am having this code

```
for i in list:
    if not not_existing_signals(i):
         #store the signal

def not_existing_signals(name_of_signal):
    for filename in Path('c:\....').glob('**/*.txt') :  
        with open(filename) as f:
            if name_of_signal in f.read():
                return True
    return False
```

What i am trying to do is to check if an element of my **list** does not exist anywhere inside the folder,if it exists at least in one file i won't need to store it somewhere.

**UPDATE**

So what i want is to search for a`signal name` in the folder not in each file separately and see if it not exists

I have about 100 signal names . So for example if one of them is in the third file , the program will return false because it will check that it's not on the first and second file. I want to return false if a signal is nowhere on the three files

Comment: *I know the logic of this code is wrong* - how do you know, by what symptoms ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Because it prints all my signals instead the ones that are missing from all the files. Probably it's checking only the file that is currently on "open".if it's not there it's returning false. i want to check all the files and then somehow return false

Comment: you are saying contradiction now: -- from question "if it exists at least in **one** file" -- from your comment "i want to check **all** the files"

Comment: Please state your problem and expected output clearly. Even better, you can produce a comprehensive input and the expected output. If English is not your first language, a bullet list and practical example may help.

Comment: Sorry guys as @Gsk said english is not my first language. Hope it's better now

Comment: Do you need to do this in python? Otherwise use grep on linux

Comment: From your update, I do understand that you want to return `False` if `name_of_signal` is in at least one file. This means that the function returns `True` if `name_of_signal` is **not present** in all the files. If that's what you want to do, just switch `return True` and `return False`

Comment: @Gsk i just want to get the signal that is missing from all the files. So get signal_name and check file1,file2,file3. If you don't find it anywhere in these 3 files that's correct(that's what i want).

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested? Should work

Comment: @Gsk i tried it and it still prints everything :/

Comment: @Gsk Sorry for late response. Turns out you are right :) If you want you can paste it as an answer and i can accept it. Either way thank you so much

Comment: @AlexKolydas happy that it works. Posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're trying to build *checks if a word (i.e. `name_of_signal`) is not present in any file in a directory*.
This means that you expect `False` to be returned if at least 1 file contains `name_of_signal`, `True` if all the files do not contain `name_of_signal`.

This can be conceptualized as:

> For each file in my folder, open the file and check if it contains the word `name_of_signal`. If the word is in the file, you can stop the iteration and return `False` (since the requirement is *at least one file*). If the word is not in the file, continue with the next file

Your function is correct, but it checks the exact opposite: instead of checking *if a word is not contained in any file*, you check *if a word is contained in at least on file*:

```
def not_existing_signals(name_of_signal):               # FUNCTION DEFINITION
    for filename in Path('c:\....').glob('**/*.txt') :  # for each file in folder
        with open(filename) as f:                       # open the file
            if name_of_signal in f.read():              # if name_of_signal is in the file
                return True                             # stop the iteration and return True
    return False                                        # if we've looked inside all the files and didn't found name_of_signal, return False
```

**SOLUTION:**

The solution is simply to exchange the `return True` with the `return False`:

```
def not_existing_signals(name_of_signal):               # FUNCTION DEFINITION
    for filename in Path('c:\....').glob('**/*.txt') :  # for each file in folder
        with open(filename) as f:                       # open the file
            if name_of_signal in f.read():              # if name_of_signal is in the file
                return False                            # stop the iteration and return False (MEANS: found at least one file with name_of_signal
    return True                                         # if we've looked inside all the files and didn't found name_of_signal, return True (MEANS: name_of_signals is not in the files!)
```

If you don't want to change the code, you can simply change the name of your function:

from `not_existing_signals` to `existing_signals` !!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Regex](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp).
Try this:

```
import re
search = ((re.findall(name_of_signal,f.read(), re.IGNORECASE)))
```

What I put together above may not work, but using regex is probably the most efficient way to achieve what you're trying to do.